# Convert array to list by using dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

if you have an array, and you want to convert it by using your defined dictionary, how do you do?
input:

```
my_dict = {1 : 'J',2:'F', 3:'M',4: 'A',5: 'M',6 : 'J',7:'J', 8:'A',9: 'S',10: '0',11 : 'N',12:'D'}
x=np.array(2,6,8,1,.....)
```

output:

```
y=("F","J","A","J",.....)
```

We have tried this:

```
my_dict = {1 : 'J',2:'F', 3:'M',4: 'A',5: 'M',6 : 'J',7:'J', 8:'A',9: 'S',10: '0',11 : 'N',12:'D'}
a = np.empty(len(x))
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    b=my_dict[x[i,0]]
    a[i,0]=b
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you are using numpy here is beyond me and please note that your numpy arrange initialization syntax is incorrect. But you said output that looks like

```
 ("F","J","A","J",.....)
```

for that you need something like:

```
import numpy as np
my_dict = {1 : 'J',2:'F', 3:'M',4: 'A',5: 'M',6 : 'J',7:'J', 8:'A',9: 'S',10: '0',11 : 'N',12:'D'}
x=np.array([2,6,8,1,10,11])

[my_dict[i] for i in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why numpy but this code will work:

```
my_dict = {1 : 'J',2:'F', 3:'M',4: 'A',5: 'M',6 : 'J',7:'J', 8:'A',9: 'S',10: '0',11 : 'N',12:'D'}
x=[2,6,8,1,10,11]

result=[]
for key in  x:
    result.append(my_dict[key]);

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

`dict.get()` won't throw KeyNotFoundError exception if the key doesn't exist.

```
my_dict = {1 : 'J',2:'F', 3:'M',4: 'A',5: 'M',6 : 'J',7:'J', 8:'A',9: 'S',10: '0',11 : 'N',12:'D'}

# With KeyNotFoundError handled
x=[my_dict.get(i) for i in [2,6,8,1,10,11]]
```